# How to make a sharepoint 2010 public site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a share point local site .How can I make this as a public site (eg: www.abcde.com).Which are the steps I have to follow? I searched for the solution and haven't got.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "Alternate Access Mappings in Sharepoint" in Google